# Pass data in form of variable -Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I am trying to implement high charts(pai chart) in my system where I am trying to pass the the value of data from a variable which contains the value in exact array manner that data required, `alert(legend_with_values)` If I am alerting this variable it returns `[['agent_total_members',24],['billing_failed',0],['members_inactive',0],['members_expired',0] ]` I am Passing this value to the data field like this

```
 legend_with_values;
 alert(legend_with_values);
```

> this alert returns [['agent_total_members',24],['billing_failed',0],['members_inactive',0],['members_expired',0]

```
  options.series = [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Legend',
    data: legend_with_values
  }];
  new Highcharts.Chart(options);`
```

But when I am passing this variable in data it is coming in this manner .Check the image it is taking each character as a string [image: e]

and if I put the alert value statically in the data it is showing me graph properly any suggestions how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

I edited your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3rkd8/ and all is generated properly.

```
var chart,
    legend_with_values = [['agent_total_members',24],['billing_failed',0],['members_inactive',0],['members_expired',0],['agent_total_members',45]];
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: legend_with_values
        }]
    });
});
```

Could you update this example if you have different source code and problem still exist?