# Highcharts PHP/MYSQL array issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I am trying to generate a highcharts piechart from a php array. This array has data that is pulled from a mysql database. The problem is the chart is not generating correctly and i suspect the problem is something to do with the json format of the php variable. Unfortunately highcharts does not provide any errors, the chart does simply not display.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("MyDatabase", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, goals FROM players limit 5");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$row[0] = $r['name'];
$row[1] = $r['goals'];
array_push($rows,$row);
}

$test=json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $test;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Pie Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(function () {
var chart,
    mydata = <? echo $test ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test chart'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Goals Scored',
            data: mydata
        }]
    });
});

});
</script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i echo $test i get the following json format:

> [["Name1",1],["Name2",2],["Name3",3],["Name4",4],["Name5",5]]

I believe this is the correct format because when i manually enter this data, the chart displays e.g.

```
<script>
$(function () {
var chart,
$(document).ready(function() {
mydata = [["Name1",1],["Name2",2],["Name3",3],["Name4",4],["Name5",5]];
$(document).ready(function() {
.......rest of the code.......
</script>
```

I have done some research of the problem and similar problems were discussed in 
[JSON and Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968453/json-and-highcharts)
[Pass data in form of variable -Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744861/pass-data-in-form-of-variable-highcharts)
[Can't get PHP variables in the JS script when setting Highcharts head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087592/cant-get-php-variables-in-the-js-script-when-setting-highcharts-head-tag)
but none of the proposed solutions seemed to fix my problem. I have been stuck trying to find a fix for the past week :(
As mentioned at the start i believe the problem is linked to the json format but then why is the format working when i enter the data manually in the exact same format?

I should also say that i am a noob at php, highcharts and mysql but i am enjoying learning about them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(mydata)` after `mydata = <? echo $test ?>;` to see if it's in the correct format?

Comment: i just tried that with firebug and i get SyntaxError: syntax error  chart.php (line 11, col 13)

Comment: the main reason i'm confused though is because the chart works if i manually input the data (in json format) but when i echo $test it does'nt....

Comment: That's why I asked what I asked. Try console.log for mydata after echo to see if it's in the correct format. If it's working with manual input but not with echo, maybe it's the echo that's stuffing up the format of mydata. It's putting extra " or something?

Comment: When i click on the error in console i get:    SyntaxError: syntax error
mydata = <? echo $test ?>;
---------^   with the arrow pointing at the first <.
 
Is that what you need? Or do you need more information? (Apologies, i only downloaded firebug a few days ago so still learning about it)

Comment: I think your $test is undefined by the time you get to assigning it to mydata. Try declaring it globally.

Comment: How are you running PHP?  If you are getting a JavaScript syntax error at `mydata = <? echo $test ?>` that means PHP is not pre-processing and replacing that statement.  I tried your code on a PHP command line and it looks fine to me.

Comment: i'm running the page on localhost using xampp with apache. Apache is using phpmyadmin to manage the PHP. I also tried running the PHP code (with the mysql query) immediately above the highcharts script but that did'nt work either. Is there anything i can do to remedy php not pre-processing?

Comment: ***Ok i think i fixed it! For some reason it was'nt working when i used <? ...php code goes here....  ?>   but when i use <?php  ...php code goes here... ?> then it works. So starting with <?php made the difference. Thanks for all the help everyone!!!